# Image of extension ideal classes homomorphism in ideal class group under Artin map in class field theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K/P$ be a finite extension of number fields and $\epsilon_{K/P}:[\mathfrak{a}] \in Cl(P) \rightarrow [\mathfrak{a}.\mathcal{O}_K]\in Cl(K)$ be the ideal class transfer homomorphism. It's well known that there exists an isomorphism $\gamma:Cl(K) \rightarrow Gal(H_K/K)$ by $[\mathfrak{b}] \mapsto \left( \frac{H_K/K}{\mathfrak{b}}\right)$ (the Artin symbol at $\mathfrak{b}$), for the Hilbert class field $H_K$ of K. Is there any result (s) about the combination $\gamma \circ \epsilon_{K/P}$?

Comment: This is known as the "Verlagerung" map (German for "transfer"). It doesn't have a particularly nice description purely on the Galois side. If you google for "class field theory" and "Verlagerung" you'll find plenty of references.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.Using the "transfer map", I want to see what happens in $P \subseteq F \subseteq K$ a tower of finite extensions of number fields. Roughly  speaking, what is the image of "combination" of transfer maps?

Comment: Harvey Cohn has written repeatedly about transfer maps in class field theory in his books on algebraic number theory and the construction of class fields.